# TASK: react-native-doc-viewer compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting this errorr while taking android build react-native, screenshot provided below

```
TASK: react-native-doc-viewer compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED   
package com.facebook.react.views.webview does not exist
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H17A8.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deprecated `class com.facebook.react.views.webview` is not actually being used. It is just a redundant import. Could be fixed by removing the `import in node_modules/react-native-doc-viewer/android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/RNReactNativeDocViewerModule.java`

Remove the ununsed import:

```
import com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager;
```